# Uploading public macOS code to GitHub with no signing?

Tags: xcode, code-signing-certificate

This may be completely noob, but I keep having this issue and I'm wondering if there's a trivial solution.

I am downloading sample projects from GitHub to see how to implement a lexer/parser/interpreter. [Here](https://github.com/igorkulman/SwiftPascalInterpreter) is an example. Invariably, the macOS (or iOS) portion of these samples have the original author's signing applied, which then causes it to fail to build on my machine.

Sure, it's easy enough to fix this (with the exception that double-clicking the error does not take you to the screen) but that leads to my questions:

1) is there an *easy* way to avoid causing this problem for others when I upload my projects to git(etc)?

2) is there an easy way to reset the signing automatically when I download other people's code?

Comment: Look into `SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR`. Not sure if it’s still relevant. Apple uses it in its sample projects. Basically a user defined Xcode config value: https://github.com/DanielStormApps/SMC/blob/1497025637a52f63e6bfe090242c6fc978f3713d/smc/smc-project/configuration/SampleCode.xcconfig

Comment: OK I'll take a look, thanks.